# Filter with booleanfields values

Tags: django

I have such model

```
Post (models.Model):
recommended = models.BooleanField (default=False)
```

when I get all objects from model I have

```
posts = Post.objects.all()
posts.count() # show equals to 18

posts[0].recommended # equals to False
```

but when I try to filter it by recommended tag I get total count equals to 0 even in model they all have the same value as I request in filter

```
 posts = Post.objects.filter(recommended=False)
 posts.count() # show equals to 0
```

Looks like there was not any values in this field because there vas crated before I make this field in model

Comment: How are you inserting the objects into the db?

Comment: Maybe `Post.objects.filter(recommended__exact=False)`?

Comment: Do `print posts.query` and post it as well.

Comment: do you get `0` when you do `Post.objects.filter(recommended=True)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch objects that have either False or NULL value you can do it like this:

```
Post.objects.exclude(recommended=True)
```

Although I'd rather suggest to fix your database by issuing an `UPDATE` query that will change all `NULL` values to `False` (do it from django shell):

```
Post.objects.filter(recommended__isnull=True).update(recommended=False)
```

It would be also good to alter your table to include `NOT NULL` in column definition.